# Passing a function parameter to change a div style properties

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to solve this problem:  I want to pass a function parameter to select a div so I can change the style.top position with an interval.

```
var yPos = 0;
var divOne = document.getElementById("div1");
var divTwo = document.getElementById("div2");
var divThree = document.getElementById("div3");
.....

function jump(which){
    yPos++;
    (which).style.top = yPos + "px";
    var jumpTimeOut = setTimeout(jump,100,which);
    if(yPos > 500){
    clearTimeout(jumpTimeOut);
    }
}

jump("divOne");
```

I could use a switch statement for each div variable, but there is a lot of divs in the program, so I was wondering if there is a way to concatenate the div name with a function parameter. Needles to say I'm getting can't change properties style of NULL with the current code.

Any help is appreciated

---->> I found a solution, I passed the div name string "div1" as parameter inside the function, so I can get the div again with a inside variable:

```
var divOne = document.getElementById("div1");
var divTwo = document.getElementById("div2");

function jump(which){
    var jumpingDiv = document.getElementById(which);
    yPos++;
    jumpingDiv.style.top = yPos + "px";
    var jumpTimeOut = setTimeout(jump,100,which);
        if(yPos > 500){
        clearTimeout(jumpTimeOut);
    }
}

jump("div1");
```

Odd solution I think, but its working so.. hehe.

Comment: I found this error in console : ` Uncaught ReferenceError: yPos is not defined`

Comment: Ohh yeah sorry, yPos is defined previously I forgot to added it.

Comment: Why you are passing a variable name as string? I think `jump("divOne");` this should be `jump(divOne);`. Or this is a typo?

Comment: Is not a typo, I tried that first passing the variable: jump(divOne) I get "I can't change properties style of null"

Comment: Well then most likely `document.getElementById("div1")` resulted in `null` already – because you are executing that code before the DOM elements even exist.

Comment: You need to pass the correct ID to `document.getElementById()`; it doesn't look at JavaScript variables. So you always have to pass `div1` (ID), not `divOne` (variable name).